# Arbitrary index (column name) for jqGrid search

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a `jqGrid` column defined as follows

```
        name : 'idmycolumn',
        index : 'idmycolumn',
        width : 80,
        align : 'right',
        search : true,
```

The id name (`ìdmycolumn`) is fine for my SQL update operations, but not with the search. How can I change the name for a search operation (to be another id, let's say `idmysearch`)?

So basically I need a different SQL column for update as I need for search. Any chance to do so?

---

Further clarification as of Oleg's question below

- How you fill rowid in the grid? Integer value of the first column
- Is idmycolumn the rowid? Do you use `key: true` in the column? No, not rowid
- Which editing mode do you use? Which searching do you use (toolbar searching, searching dialog, both)? Inline edit, toolbar search
- Which name you need to use during sorting by the `idmycolumn` column? Should by the column name for searching and sorting be the same? search should be "idmysearch", anything else (sort, ..) "idmycolumn"
- Do you use `loadonce: true` option or not? loadonce: default / false

Clarification part II:

As I have not set `stringResult = true` somewhere (I have just checked), the [default](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) is `false`. That parameter is a good hint anyway, thanks.

However, I also do parsing of the filter on the server side and this is where I currently replace `idmycolumn` with `idmysearch`. I was only wondering if I could replace that filter name upfront on client side before I send the filter to the server.

Comment: How you fill rowid in the grid? Is `idmycolumn` is the rowid? Do you use `key: true` in the column? Which editing mode you use? Which searching you use (toolbar searching, searching dialog, both)? Which name you need to use during **sorting** by the `idmycolumn` column? Should by the column name for searching and sorting be the same? Do you use `loadonce: true` option or not?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, clarification above

Comment: If you use toolbar search and you don't use `loadonce: true` then there are one more option. The format of the data for searching depend on the options of `filterToolbar` which you use. The default value of `stringResult` option is `false` (I personally use always `stringResult: true` format and process [filters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options) on the server). So it means that jqGrid just add `idmycolumn=searchingValue` as additional parameter which will be sent to the server. Do you have the case? Do you want to change the name of the parameter?

Comment: See above, and yes, I am looking for an easy way to replace that parameter name before I send it. As an alternative I can replace it on server side (as I do now). I have mainly asked the question to see if client or server-side replacement is easier. +1 for the `stringResult`hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution depends very hard from the methods which you use. jqGrid provides many options which could be used to change behavior of the methods or format of parameters which will be send for example to the server. Moreover there are many callbacks and events which allows you to modify parameters *before* sending to the server. It's important to understand that the searching parameters will be saved inside of `postData` option. All options are inside of an object which you can get by using `$("#gridid").jqGrid("getGridParam")`, alternatively you can get specific option, for example `postData` option by using `$("#gridid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData")`. The returned value is *the reference* of internal object used by jqGrid. So you can modify it and jqGrid will use automatically modified value. The usage of methods like `setGridParam` is not needed in the case.

Thus the solution of your problem could be the following. You add `beforeSearch` callback to `filterToolbar` method, which modifies the `idmycolumn` property of `postData` from `idmycolumn` to `idmysearch`:

```
$("#gridid").jqGrid("filterToolbar", {
    beforeSearch: function () {
        var postData = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData");
        if (postData.hasOwnProperty("idmycolumn")) {
            postData.idmysearch = postData.idmycolumn;
            delete postData.idmycolumn;
        }
    }
});
```